# Correct way to pass huge JSON API response (Django REST)

Tags: python, json, django-rest-framework, httpresponse

I have a task to pass huge JSON response and would like to understand what is the best practice for that.

What I'm doing right now is using `StreamHttpResponse`:

```
def generator_chunk():
    ...
    yield df.to_json   # returns data like [json]

@api_view(['GET'])
def return_data(request):
    ...
    return StreamHttpResponse(generator_chunk)  # streams data like [json][json], which is not proper json format
```

Few options I have right now on how to solve it:

1. Create temp file and store all chunks there - then stream with `StreamHttpResponse`.
2. Use `PageNumberPagination` or smth similar - to have next/prev links.

These 2 approaches are new to me, so I want to understand which one is better. Especially interested in option 1. Or if neither, how it can be handled correctly.

P.S. What I mean by huge - if table results count is > # of rows that can be read from database at once.

Comment: To what kind of clients are you sending the response. From my opinion it depends on the scenario. Delivering the data is one thing, but storing and working with the data on client side is the other thing. For example if you are browsing with you mobile device on a newspapaer page and you get a list of articles (title, image, short description) do you really need to get all 1000 articles shortcuts at once? Not really. The page will reload more articles when you scroll through the list. So Pagination is used here. If you have data which relate to each other (e.g. a huge image) you need all.

Comment: @MisterNox thank you for your comment. I'm sending data to UI (list of records) + exposing via API call. You're right, it might be too much of data to get at once. I thought about pagination but since I'm querying db in chunks, I'm getting generator and I can't slice it. So looks like I would need to store data in temp file first (exhaust generator) and then use either stream or pagination. What do you think?